# Change incoming Outlook mail subject

Tags: vba, email, outlook, outlook-2007

I have a rule running on incoming mail that moves items with a certain string in their subject line to a folder. It then runs a script to replace part of the subject with something else.

I've put break points in the script to make sure it's running and not a macro security issue. It reads the subject but just won't save the change. I got the script from someone looking for a similar result

```
Sub RunAScriptRuleRoutine(MyMail As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim strID As String
Dim olNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem

strID = MyMail.EntryID
Set olNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olMail = olNS.GetItemFromID(strID)
' do stuff with olMail, e.g.
olMail.Subject = Replace(objMail.Subject, "[Jira]", "something else")
olMail.Save

Set olMail = Nothing
Set olNS = Nothing
End Sub
```

I know the above is overkill, so I've also checked it with much simpler code but still no success, it just keeps the same subject line that it came in with.

```
Public Sub Whatever(Mail As Outlook.MailItem)
Mail.Subject = "Hello"
Mail.Save
End Sub
```

It seems like I'm misunderstanding the MailItem.Save Method but I can't work it out.

I'm using Outlook 2007.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Does not appear to be anything wrong with the second example.

For the first example you are missing Option Explicit

Which would lead you to change objMail to olMail

```
olMail.Subject = Replace(olMail.Subject, "[Jira]", "something else")
```

Comment: One may also want to change the `.ConversationTopic` , not only the `.Subject`.

Answer (score 0):

The [Move](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff860683(v=office.15).aspx) method of the MailItem class moves a Microsoft Outlook item to a new folder and returns an Object value that represents the item which has been moved to the designated folder.

So, you need to set the `Subject` property on the returned object, not the source one.

Comment: So should I do the move as part of the script? Or can I set the subject of the moved item after the built in Outlook move rule?